ポートフォリオ・過去作品は具体的のどういうものを作成すればいいのでしょうか？
　クラウドワークスなどでWebページのデザイナーやコーディングの仕事案件の募集をみると、「ポートフォリオ」とか「過去作品」を募集者に見てもらい、採用/不採用を決めるようです。
　　しかし私はまだ未経験で、HTML/CSSやJavaScriptを勉強している段階です。
　ポートフォリオがなんであるかは、下記の質問をみて大体はわかりました：
Web開発のポートフォリオ作成手順と学習内容について
Webページ作成に絞って、もう少し具体的に知りたいです。
　過去作品は勉強しながら作成した実際のWebページだと思いますけれども、これもどのくらいのレベルのものを望まれるのでしょうか？
例えば、
　入門書のサンプルを作成した結果とか、
　実際のwebページを書き写して、自分なりの変更を加えたものとか、
なのでしょうか？
　実際に過去に応募された方など、よろしければご教示ください。
　よろしくお願いいたします。

Web開発のポートフォリオ作成手順と学習内容について も参考にしてください。実績がないなら実績の求められない方法を検討されるしか…。新卒採用が強いのは実績を求められないからなんですよね。

ポートフォリオって今の実力を見せるものなので、実力以上のものをどこかからパクってきて提出したら、採用後に地獄を見るだけっス（あなた自身も、あなたを採用した企業側も）

ここのようなプログラミングに関するQ&Aを扱っているサイトで(間接的に)聞くよりも、実際に使いたいエージェントサイトや案件紹介サイトにあるヘルプ記事を探したり、当該サイトの窓口に直接相談したりする方が、対象や内容が明確で素早い反応が期待できるのではありませんか？

いろいろとコメントをくださり、ありがとうございます。紹介サイトをあたってみます。質問内容を一部変更したので、他にもアドバイスをしていただけると助かります。

ポートフォリオを出せと言っている相手に聞かないと。就活先が何が求めているかを知る由もない第三者しかいないここで聞いても、具体的な答えは出てこないと思います。

コメントをありがとうございます。確かにおっしゃるとおりです。一度就活先に質問して聞いてみます。
